# Javascript REGEX for deleting char only in string start and end, not in the middle

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to remove the "+" chars in some strings.

I'm using this regex:

```
string.replace(/\+/g, "");
```

The problem is when i have strings like: "+++++test+string+++" it obviously gets transformed to **teststring** and the correct result should be **test+string**.

So what i need is to figure out a regex that removes the "+" char, only at the start and end of the string.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
^\++|\++$
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/NjKUdh/1/).

---

In `JavaScript`:

```
string.replace(/^\++|\++$/g, "");
```